# Tilde not returning home directory

Tags: sudo, users, tilde

After sudo command to change user, Tilde (~) not returning current user's home directory but returning previous login user's home directory.  I needed to expand with `echo ~USERNAME` but I need to make `echo ~` to keep compatibility existing apps.

```
user1@server1:-$ whoami
user1
user1@server1:-$ sudo -u user2 -s /bin/bash
user2@server1:-$ whoami
user2


user2@server1:- echo ~
/home/user1
user2@server1:-$ echo ~user2
/home/user2
```

Answer (score 2):

`sudo` does not necessarily change the home directory of the invoker. You need to use `-H` to ensure this

```
sudo -H -u user2 -s
```

Or

```
sudo -u user2 -i
```

See `man sudo` for details

Answer (score 1):

sudo command doesn't set HOME environment variable. For this, we need to add `set_home` or `always_set_home` to `sudoers` file.